# Find number of distinct Keys in an unstructured array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to find the number of distinct keys that exist in an array of objects in an unstructured dataset 
for eg

```
[{"a":10, b:"20"}, {"a":90, "b":30}, {"b":40, "c":79}, {"b":58, "d":50}]
```

the use case is to find the distinct keys ie `[a, b, c, d]`

The particular use case can be solved using a loop but is there a smarter way of doing that?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to combine all objects to a single object, and then get the keys with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const data = [{"a":10, b:"20"}, {"a":90, "b":30}, {"b":40, "c":79}, {"b":58, "d":50}]

const keys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));

console.log(keys); // keys
console.log(keys.length); // number of keys
```